# How to show error page, when error is thrown by a function in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, next.js

I am using mongoose inside next.js, and I am directly accessing the data from it in the server component. It is working well, but I also want to show error page when mongoose throws an exception or doesn't work. So I read the document of next.js and came with a solution of adding error.tsx page which will take charge of all error automatically, but it was of no use. Then, I add the Error boundary class component which also didn't work. Let me give you a short description of my code, I want to click on the delete icon and a popup will open (dialog box to be specific) which will ask for delete conformation, on clicking on agree it will run the mongoose function of delete function and after that I will revalidate the path of the page to refresh the page. Now to check for error I am trying to manually throw error in mongoose file to see how next.js will handle that thrown error, and as I stated earlier nothing is going right for me.

**productPageActions.tsx (mongoose function file)**

```
export const deleteProduct = async (id: Types.ObjectId) => {
  try {
    console.log(id);
    throw new Error("My error");
    await Product.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    revalidatePath("/products");
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error.message);
    return { error: "thrown error" };
  }
};
```

As I said earlier i am throwing error manually in mongoose file.

**deleteHandler.tsx**

```
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";
import { deleteProduct } from "@/actions/productPageActions";
import DeleteAlertDialog from "./deleteAlertDialog";

const EditDeleteHandler = (props: { prod_id: string }) => {
  const { prod_id } = props;
  const id = JSON.parse(prod_id);
  const [openDeleteDialog, setOpenDeleteDialog] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleDeleteDialogClose = () => {
    setOpenDeleteDialog(false);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton aria-label="delete" onClick={() => setOpenDeleteDialog(true)}>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <DeleteAlertDialog
        open={openDeleteDialog}
        handleClose={handleDeleteDialogClose}
        deleteClickHandler={deleteProduct}
        id={id}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditDeleteHandler;
```

I am using above component in **page.tsx**

**deleteAlertDialog.tsx**

```
import {
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogTitle,
} from "@mui/material";
import { Types } from "mongoose";
import React from "react";
import ErrorBoundry from "./errorBoundry";

const DeleteAlertDialog = (props: {
  open: boolean;
  handleClose: () => void;
  deleteClickHandler: (id: Types.ObjectId) => Promise<{ error: string }>;
  id: Types.ObjectId;
}) => {
  const { open, handleClose, deleteClickHandler, id } = props;
  let err: boolean;
  const deleteProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const { error } = await deleteClickHandler(id); //funtion which is returning error
      if (error) {
        err = true;
      } else {
        handleClose();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("modal error");
      throw error;
    }
    if(err){
      throw new Error("unexpected error occured");
    }
  };
  return (
    <ErrorBoundry>
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
      aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
    >
      <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
        {"Are you sure you want to delete?"}
      </DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
          Deleting this will also remove all the items in this product.
        </DialogContentText>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button color="error" onClick={handleClose}>
          Disagree
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={deleteProduct} autoFocus>
          Agree
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
    </ErrorBoundry>
  );
};

export default DeleteAlertDialog;
```

**ErrorBoundry.tsx**

```
import React from "react";

class ErrorBoundry extends React.Component<
  { children: React.ReactNode },
  { hasError: boolean }
> {
  constructor(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error: Error) {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: React.ErrorInfo): void {
    console.log(error, errorInfo);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <h1>Something went wrong</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundry
```